# Have php server some .js and .css files

Tags: php, nginx, amazon-ecs

I am using two containers in AWS ECS, nginx and php and I would like to have php serve some files like for example:
/app/plugins/sitepress-multilingual-cms/templates/language-switchers/legacy-list-horizontal/style.min.css

This is my nginx.conf:

```
load_module modules/ngx_http_perl_module.so;
env PHP_SERVICE;
http {
    perl_set $php_service 'sub { return $ENV{"PHP_SERVICE"}; }';
    resolver 169.254.169.253;
    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    gzip on;
    server {
      index index.php index.html index.htm;
      listen 80;
      listen [::]:80;
      root /var/www/html/web;
      charset utf-8;

      location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
      }

      location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass ${php_service}:9000;
        include fastcgi.conf;
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
      }

      location ~* \.(css|js|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|png)$ {
       try_files $uri /index.php?$query_string;
       include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
       expires max;
       log_not_found off;
      }
    }
}
```

The problem is that I get 404 for that file and a few more:

```
https://xxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxx.xx/app/plugins/sitepress-multilingual-cms/templates/language-switchers/legacy-list-horizontal/style.min.css?ver=1
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 404
```

As I understand it nginx will use the last location to match this request and will try first to find the file locally (with the try_files) and if not find (it shouldn't since file is not there) it will pass it to /index.php.
This file doesn't exist in the nginx container but exists in the php container.

request path:

```
/app/plugins/sitepress-multilingual-cms/templates/language-switchers/legacy-list-horizontal/style.min.css?ver=1
```

nginx container:

```
/var/www/html/web # cat web/app/plugins/sitepress-multilingual-cms/templates/language-switchers/legacy-list-horizontal/style.min.css
cat: can't open 'web/app/plugins/sitepress-multilingual-cms/templates/language-switchers/legacy-list-horizontal/style.min.css': No such file or directory
```

php container

```
/var/www/html # cat web/app/plugins/sitepress-multilingual-cms/templates/language-switchers/legacy-list-horizontal/style.min.css
.wpml-ls-legacy-list-horizontal{border:1px solid transparent;padding:7px;clear:both}.wpml-ls-legacy-list-horizontal>ul{padding:0;margin:0 !important;list-style-type:none}.wpml-ls-legacy-list-horizontal .wpml-ls-item{padding:0;margin:0;list-style-type:none;display:inline-block}.wpml-ls-legacy-list-horizontal a{display:block;text-decoration:none;padding:5px 10px 6px;line-height:1}.wpml-ls-legacy-list-horizontal a span{vertical-align:middle}.wpml-ls-legacy-list-horizontal a span.wpml-ls-bracket{vertical-align:unset}.wpml-ls-legacy-list-horizontal .wpml-ls-flag{display:inline;vertical-align:middle}.wpml-ls-legacy-list-horizontal .wpml-ls-flag+span{margin-left:.4em}.rtl .wpml-ls-legacy-list-horizontal .wpml-ls-flag+span{margin-left:0;margin-right:.4em}.wpml-ls-legacy-list-horizontal.wpml-ls-statics-footer{margin-bottom:30px}.wpml-ls-legacy-list-horizontal.wpml-ls-statics-footer>ul{text-align:center}
```

What I noticed is that the content-type of all the files giving me 404 is text/html; charset=UTF-8 even if they are .js or .css so I was thinking this can be the issue. But in the php container logs I see the request as 404:

```
10.80.18.143 -  10/Aug/2022:11:00:55 +0000 "GET /index.php" 200
10.80.18.143 -  10/Aug/2022:11:00:57 +0000 "GET /index.php" 404
10.80.18.143 -  10/Aug/2022:11:00:57 +0000 "GET /index.php" 404
10.80.18.143 -  10/Aug/2022:11:00:57 +0000 "GET /index.php" 404
10.80.18.143 -  10/Aug/2022:11:00:57 +0000 "GET /index.php" 404
10.80.18.143 -  10/Aug/2022:11:00:59 +0000 "GET /index.php" 404
```

This matches the number of the files I am getting 404 for, so not sure if it's cause of PHP cannot find the file or I am getting the 404 cause of the content-type.

Thank you